# Dynamically add "comment" during validation in Handsontable

Tags: handsontable

I can see that there are ways of creating comments in the cells array before rendering, and using the context menu. But is there a way to create a comment after a change?

I originally tried this:

```
var errors = [];

var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: vendors,
    startRows: 1,
    afterChange: function(changes, source) {
        var row = changes[0][0];
        var col = changes[0][1];
        errors.push({
            row: row,
            col: col,
            comment: "Error"
        })
    comments: errors
}
```

But it seems as though changing the `errors` object doesn't automatically render the comments. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not exactly related, but we are using jQuery qtip for displaying tooltips selectively on cells matching a specific criteria whenever they are changed. It is working good.

Comment: Yeah, I gave up trying to use these a while back and just used bootstrap-tooltips for it

Comment: Did you ever find a good way to do this? Can't get it working.

Comment: There is no part of the library that looks the same after 4 years :P Can't say I remember though I think back then this simply wasn't supported.

Answer (score 2):

Comment can be added on meta object as follows

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: vendors,
    startRows: 1,
    afterChange: function(changes, source) {
        var row = changes[0][0];
        var col = changes[0][1];
        hot.getCellMeta(row, col).comment =  'Error';
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution! It is also possible to update the comment by calling [setComment()](https://handsontable.com/docs/6.2.2/Comments.html#setComment), but that re-renders the table, which kills performance. Note that in version 6.2.2, the comment field is an object: `hot.getCellMeta(row, col).comment =  {value: 'Error'};`

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, you can try this:

```
this.instance.getPlugin('comments').setCommentAtCell(row, col, "some text comment");
// or
hot_isstance.setCommentAtCell(row, col, "some text comment");
```